# Search a String in a SQL table - android

Tags: android, sql

i want a method for searching a string in my SQl table (field name) and if find it return true else return false!how can i do that?
i see other topics but nothing found ,help me please

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Databases are designed around storing and searching data...

Comment: You'll need to start at the beginning then, @MehdiAkin. Start with Google and look at a few tutorials. Telling you how to search won't get you further than the next question.

Comment: Could you please post what you already have?

Comment: @RodrigoHenriques i have sql database named x with table named 'y'! this table have a field named 'name' i want to search for a name and if find it return true

Comment: Try the first answer in the link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

select if (name="" then true else false) as name, * from table Y;